# I have the following Error 405 at flask with a simple request with params

Tags: python, flask

Hello  I am starting at flask
I am using linuxmint python 3.6.9

I am trying to use a function similar to this

```py
@app.route('/user/<username>',methods['GET'])
def show_user_profile(username):
    # show the user profile for that user
    return 'User %s' % escape(username)
```

But I always have the same error 405

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an equal sign (`=`). it should be `methods=['GET']`, not `methods['GET']`.

This should work:

```py
@app.route('/user/<username>', methods=['GET'])
def show_user_profile(username):
    # show the user profile for that user
    return 'User %s' % escape(username)
```